# Index/match with two criteria anyway to get the second set of data using unique identifiers?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've been stuck for some time trying to match up two different data spread sheets. I'm trying to match off dollar amounts with matching names that correspond to the dollar amount. I went ahead and assigned unique identifiers to each row thinking that would help me match off the amounts, but my problem comes when there are two or more dollar amounts that are the same and have the same name.. is there anyway to get the second id to show  up?

Formula sheet: (I need The second 112 to pull 113.. anyway thats possible??

```
  A        B            C          D             E             F              G
IDSheett2 IDsheet1  NameSheet1 NameSheet2   Item       AmountSheet1     AmountSheet2
  554      112      Jim           Jim            Hat          25             25
  555       112      Jim        Jim          Shoe         25                 25
```

Formula in column B2: it should go through both sheet 1 and 2 and automacially fill in the matching id - id that matches the name and amount.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(sheet1!$C$2:$C$1000,MATCH(1,INDEX((sheet1!$A$2:$A$1000=D1)*(sheet1!$B$2:$B$1000=G1),0,1),0)),"")
```

Data from Sheet2:
A= ID B= Name C= Item Name ( ID basically row 1 = 1, 2 = 2.. )

```
A   B   C   D
554 Jim Hat 25
555 jim Shoe25
```

Data from Sheet1:
A= name B= amount C= assigned ID ( ID basically row 1 = 1, 2 = 2.. )

> ```
> A      B  C
> Jim   25  112
> Jim   25  113
> ```

I'm also open to other ideas. Thanks for the help.

UPdated::: Based on comments

im not trying to create a database.. i have two sets of data that i'm trying to compare and match off like items(i take matched items and email it out to a group of people). i had to change some of the names because this is work related but the overall concept should remain.

it is Impossible for me to know how many names will be on incoming wires and how many names will be on my expected wires lists. I assigned unique ids per row on each page so i can do iferror/index/match to pull from a unique row to the main page.

What im trying to accomplish:

I have two sets of data: Sheet1 is incoming wires (it gives me a name and an amount) Sheet 2 is the account name, Item its for, and expected amount.

I'm trying to match the name and amount on the formula sheet but i run into the problem of two items with the same name and the same amount only pulling the first ID number it runs into and this becomes a problem because i have another vba code that will delete multiple ID's so i know i'm not counting something twice.

my final page should read:

```
   ID sheet2   IDsheet1     Name       Item(sheet2)      Amount
    554           112         JIM       Hat            25
    555           113         JIM        Shoe           25
```

but right now the 113 id wont pull and it will just be 112 twice (which will end up getting deleted so i will miss that second match)

..+ everything works perfectly unless there are two items for the same name and the same amount +.. that is the only time i run into this problem.

Is there any code or process that can have the sheet realize that it has already used the ID of 112 once and then automatically fill in the id of 113 (so it won't get deleted by my vba code)?

Comment: It looks like you may be using Excel to create a database. Excel is not a great tool for this. Are you limited to using Excel for this? Could you explain what you are actually trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: Updated Summary per your guys' comments - My formulas work except for when there is an item with the same name and same amount - trying to get it to pull the second ID instead of copying the first id for each time.

Comment: thank you guys for taking a look and trying to help.

Comment: Also the Item description comes from the expected items report and i can't link that to incoming wires page (it pulls to the main page by the id from sheet 2 with an inferror/index/match formula) so my only things to match off are by using the ID assigned, name, and amounts.. unless there is another way that i can't see.

Comment: By using sheet2 to get your unique IDs how do you know which name/price pair aligns to the sheet 1 ID? For example, you could have just as easily said that you want B2's value to be 113 and B3 to be 112... Or does it not matter which sheet2 line item gets assigned to sheet1, as long as the name and price match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your formula sheet, B2 and copied down:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$C$2:$C$1000,MATCH(1,INDEX((Sheet1!$A$2:$A$1000=D2)*(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$1000=G2)*(COUNTIF(B$1:B1,Sheet1!$C$2:$C$1000)=0),),0)),"")
```

Comment: Genius! this is exactly what i wanted - i'm new to this so i don't know if there is a way to give points or mark this solved so if there is please let me know. Thank you!!

Comment: There's a check box next to the answer that tiger posted. You can accept by clicking that checkmark

Comment: While i have you guys here - Are you aware of a way to add a variance to my sheet - Say the Wire amount on sheet 1 is actually 24.95 and i'm expecting 25 on sheet 2 - can you suggest formula or change to my current setup to account for a variance??

Comment: You could try the `ROUND` function

Comment: hey @tigeravatar, could you explain how the `COUNTIF` part of your formula works? I had thought of a similar solution but did it in a much more complicated manner than you (i.e. counting instances of repeats, then using `ROW` and `SMALL` to pick subsequent matches..

Comment: @Jaycal Sorry for the late reply.  The `COUNTIF` is simply looking at previous entries to make sure that there are no repeats.

Comment: got that part, but the part I'm hung up on is the countif criteria; should it really be the prices on sheet 1 (column C)? Or should it be Column C in the OPs formula sheet (where the names are)?

Comment: It is checking the prices that have already come in, so it has to be on column C (which is the main - outer - Index target).  If it were to do a different column, it would have no effect on the formula results.